# Force add 'https://' in my cspecific pages by htaccess

Tags: wordpress

I have a website built with WordPress cms, i want to add https:// on my contact page by htaccess file of website. I have try different think but i an not able to do it. Here is the site [link](http://alacartesites.com/contact/)

Please share if have any idea!.

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess - add this logic.

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} contact
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://alacartesites.com/contact/$1 [R,L]
```

Ref: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file, it worked for me. I verified. Please use the below one.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(contact|contact/)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: i have add above code but when i run my url it show "https://alacartesites.com/contact/contact/contact/contact/contact/contact/contact/contact/contact/contact/contact/contact/"

Comment: Remove existing rules. And Try this one. it worked for me fine. Line 1. RewriteEngine On
2. RewriredCont %{HTTPS} !=on 3. RewriteRule ^(contact|contact\/)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

Answer (score 0):

If you have https enabled for your domain, it would be a good idea to use it for the entire website, not just for one/some pages only.

To redirect all existing pages from http to HTTPS, you can use the following .htaccess code snippet:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I understand that. But I cannot see any possible reason why you wouldn't/shouldn't use HTTPS for the whole website.

Comment: I have used above code its working for all pages but this is no my solution. can you say any other ......